# Page ViewController with 4 viewControllers - How to set view 2 as initial viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have created a pageViewController with four view controller.

Right now the order is:

VC1, VC2, VC3, VC4:

```
var pageControl = UIPageControl()
var pendingPage: Int?

lazy var viewControllerList: [UIViewController] = {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1")
    let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2")
    let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3")
    let vc4 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC4")

    return [vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4]
}()
```

How can I set VC2 as the initial view controller of the page view controller when the app loads? So basically the user can swipe left "and" right to got to from VC2 left to VC1 or right from VC2 to VC3.

VC1 < VC2 - this is the start view controller > VC3 > VC4

This is my viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first {
        self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    self.setViewControllers([viewControllerList[1]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Why are you using `if let` here?

Comment: I tried that on my own first, but I got this error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UIViewController' @maddy I am using if let because I want to make sure that the ViewControllerList is empty for some reason, although I know that it cannot be empty.

Comment: @rmaddy as his code but i know no need for it if for sure it's not empty

Comment: I tried your suggested Solution without the "if let" statement and it works. Can you explain why the if let has thrown that error message when I am not choose the first element of the array?

Comment: the error says that you can use if let for parameter that is optional not declared explicity like what you did in **viewControllerList** ----- viewControllerList[1] is considered not optional , but viewControllerList.first is optional you can find that when you type .first extension look in the return type in suggested menu

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!